# Hide Price in Gravity Form Options Field

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I need to hide the +100 or -100 price next to the values in my option field. 
The preview for the form looks like this with the prices under accommodations:

http://trailtalkpc.com/trailtalkwp/?gf_page=preview&id=3

I tried to target the prices in CSS and use {display:none;} to hide them but am having trouble with it. So far I've been able to target the options with this:

.medium.gfield_select {display:none;}

This targets the entire drop-down menu. Anyone know how to target the prices from here? Here is the code I have been looking through to target the prices:

```
<select name="input_12" id="input_3_12" class="medium gfield_select"      

tabindex="11">

<option value="Bare Bones (No Accommodation Needed)|2500" price="">

Bare  Bones (No Accommodation Needed) </option><option value="Washington   

School House: Town House|5000" price=" +$2,500.00">Washington School House: 

Town House  +$2,500.00</option><option value="Newpark Resort: 1 Room 

Suite|4000" price=" +$1,500.00">Newpark Resort: 1 Room Suite  

+$1,500.00</option><option value="Newpark Resort: (Family) Townhouse|4500" 

price=" +$2,000.00">Newpark Resort: (Family) Townhouse  +$2,000.00</option>

<option value="Waldorf Astoria: King Suite|4000" price=" +$1,500.00">Waldorf 

Astoria: King Suite  +$1,500.00</option>

</select>
```

Thanks!

Jen

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your theme's footer or within GF HTML Field. Worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gform_format_option_label( fullLabel, fieldLabel, priceLabel, selectedPrice, price, formId, fieldId ) { 
        return fieldLabel;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly assinging css to part of text is not possible. You need to run a javascript after form load which will wrap the price inside span. Assign a class to span and define display:none for span class.

Comment: Awesome thank you! So I am using this javascript: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html  but I am having trouble figuring out how to target the price! Do you have any ideas?